# Java Creating a function out of existing code

Tags: java

I am trying to convert some (ugly looking) code into functions, such that everything is better managable. However I have come to a problem, current code:

```
    int red = card.getColor().getRed();
    int green = card.getColor().getGreen();
    int blue = card.getColor().getBlue();
    Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);

    int width;
    int height;
    int xOffset;
    int yOffset;
    int border;

    //Whole card
    width = CARD_DIMENSION.width;
    height = CARD_DIMENSION.height;
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;
    border = 5;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int dx = Math.min(x, width - 1 - x);
            int dy = Math.min(y, height - 1 - y);
            if (dx < border || dy < border) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 255 - Math.min(dx, dy)));
            }
            else {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 192 - Math.min(dx, dy)));
            }
            g2d.drawLine(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, x + xOffset, y + yOffset);
        }
    }
```

I would have to copy this everytime I want to draw some new rectangle. At first sight it isn't hard to put it in a function, however these lines:

```
            if (dx < border || dy < border) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 255 - Math.min(dx, dy)));
            }
            else {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 192 - Math.min(dx, dy)));
            }
```

They make it hard since I use dx and dy there.

Now I have come up with a proposed solution which I would want to use with anonymous inner classes and overriding the two functions:

```
private abstract class CustomRectangle {
    protected final int width;
    protected final int height;
    protected final int xOffset;
    protected final int yOffset;
    protected final int borderSize;

    public CustomRectangle(final int width, final int height, final int xOffset, final int yOffset, final int borderSize) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
        this.borderSize = borderSize;
    }

    abstract void inBorder();

    abstract void outBorder();

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int dx = Math.min(x, width - 1 - x);
                int dy = Math.min(y, height - 1 - y);
                if (dx < borderSize || dy < borderSize) {
                    inBorder();
                }
                else {
                    outBorder();
                }
                g2d.drawLine(x + xOffset, y + yOffset, x + xOffset, y + yOffset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am still afraid that it will be hard if not impossible to put in a formula using dx and dy (two local variables to the for loops).

I would appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions on either the general problem or on my own approach, because having several codeblocks that do essentially the same is just not acceptable.

Regards.

Comment: so pass `dx, dy` to the method as parameters...?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  I only ask as Eclipse has some awesome shortcut keys to rip stuff out into separate methods automatically for you.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post, netbeans can strip out code into methods for you automatically when you highlight it, I find it really useful in Eclipse when refactoring to make sure I don't break anything :)

Comment: @david99world did you miss out the link you were referring to?